# Error says: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Full Error:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
() defined in com.example.westderepostel.ChatroomActivity.ChatMessage
(String, String, String, Long) defined in com.example.westderepostel.ChatroomActivity.ChatMessage

My code:

```
class  ChatMessage(val id: String, val text: String, val fromId: String, timestamp: Long) {
    constructor() : this(id: "", text: "", fromId: "", timestamp: -1)
}
```

Please I have turned round and round unsuccessfully on this error. I will be grateful if someone come to my rescue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used inappropriate syntax for passing named arguments to the primary constructor. You should use `=` instead of `:`:

```
class  ChatMessage(val id: String, val text: String, val fromId: String, timestamp: Long) {
    constructor() : this(id = "", text = "", fromId = "", timestamp = -1)
}
```

Of course you can omit argument names entirely.